# Convert XmlNodeList to XmlNode[]

Tags: c#, xml, .net-2.0

I have a external library that requires a "XmlNode[]" instead of XmlNodeList. Is there a direct way to do this without iterating over and transferring each node?

I dont want to do this:

```
XmlNode[] exportNodes = XmlNode[myNodeList.Count];
int i = 0;
foreach(XmlNode someNode in myNodeList) { exportNodes[i++] = someNode; }
```

I am doing this in .NET 2.0 so I need a solution without linq.

Comment: is there some reason not to iterate over the `XmlNodeList` and use it to load the `XmlNode[]`? Because if you'd done that, you'd be finished by now.

Comment: No reason, thats the current implementation. It just seems odd to my that it cant be done with more compiler semantics.

Comment: The compiler semantics for this are in the newer versions of C#/.NET :) If you're stuck with an older version, then you're stuck with what you've got.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (VS2008 and target framework == 2.0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.LoadXml("<a><b /><b /><b /></a>");
    XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//b");
    XmlNode[] array = (
        new System.Collections.Generic.List<XmlNode>(
            Shim<XmlNode>(xmlNodeList))).ToArray();
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Shim<T>(System.Collections.IEnumerable enumerable)
{
    foreach (object current in enumerable)
    {
        yield return (T)current;
    }
}
```

Hints from here: [IEnumerable and IEnumerable(Of T) 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2007/10/04/ienumerable-and-ienumerable-of-t-2.aspx)

Comment: @CaTx OP asked for a solution without Linq, and other answers use it. The `Shim` method is offered as an extension method, so it can be reused and placed in another class with other extensions methods. If you have different requirements, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 20):

How about this straightfoward way...

```
var list = new List<XmlNode>(xml.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("nodeName").OfType<XmlNode>());
var itemArray = list.ToArray();
```

No need for extension methods etc...

Comment: `OfType` is a LINQ extension.

Answer (score 13):

```
 XmlNode[] nodeArray = myXmlNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>().ToArray();
```